# I can't create websites because the associations don't appear in IIS Express 10

Tags: iis, iis-7.5, iis-6, iis-express, iis-8

I can't create websites, because the associations don't appear in IIS Express 10. I've activated almost everything and restarted and nothing changes, any solution?

[image: Error]

I'm trying to install this site via IIS, but I can't get past this part

Comment: What's the operating system?

Comment: Microsoft Windows 10

Comment: I've tried uninstalling it and then installing it again and it's still the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to Control panel --> Programs and Features

1. Turn Windows features on or off
2. Unchecked "Internet Information Services" (IIS) and "Windows Process Activation Service" (WAS)
3. OK ....
4. You must restart your computer when the Windows started

Go to Control panel --> Programs and Features

1. Turn Windows features on or off
2. Checked "Internet Information Services" (IIS) and "Windows Process Activation Service" (WAS)
3. OK